# How to check compare data from two json data?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

My json data for displaying details of particular post is

http://127.0.0.1:8000/listings/

```
{"data": {"pid": 109, "name": "Labs", "website": "service.com",  "status": true}
```

My json data for complete profile details is

http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/

```
{"status": true, "data": {"basic": {"name": "Kuis", "is_new": false, "is_email_verified": false, "is_phone_verified": false}, "listings": [{"pid": 109, "nams": "Labs","created_at": "2018-02-14", "validity": "2019-06-29", "views": 2, "gstno": "09485481072", "is_featured": false },{"pid": 112, "nams": "Labs12","created_at": "2018-02-15", "validity": "2019-06-29", "views": 2, "gstno": "09499481072", "is_featured": false }], "total_listings": 2}}
```

So, now I am giving an edit option. So, i need to check whether the pid exits in the profile data? How can I able to achieve the same?

**My vue js code is**

```
mounted() {
    var self = this;
    data = {};
    data['auth-token'] = this.authType;
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/",
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (e) {
            if (e.status == 1) {
                self.listings = e.data.listings;
            }
        },
    });
    data = {};
    data['auth-token'] = this.authType;
    data['pid'] = this.pid;
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/listings/",
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (e) {
            if (e.status == 1) {
                self.data = e.data;
            }
        },
    });
},
```

I have listings data in `data[]` and all listings data from profile in `listings[]`.

I need to compare `pid` in `data[]` is present in `listings[]`.

I need to achieve the following in `HTML` side

```
<div if="data.pid == listings.pid"> Success </div> <div v-else> Failure</div>
```

I am a beginner and only know the basics. Please help me to have a solution.

Comment: are you needed to check pid in data[] is present in the listings [] which contain different pid's

Comment: yes sir.. i need.. how to check using a loop?

Comment: So you are basically saying that you get one specific profile from your `API` and store it in `data` and all listed profiles from another `API` in `listings` and want to check if that specific profile in `data` is to be found in `listings`, correct?

Comment: Sir, in data[], i am storing a particular listing. In listings[], I am storing all listings. I need to pid in data[] is present in listings[].

Comment: Provide a concrete example, how data and listings look like, so the people can help you

Comment: @Legends, he did just that, although the data is formatted in a way that is not all that readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the listing is an array and not an object you need to loop over it with index:

```
function checkOccurence(data, listing) {
  let dataFound = false;
  for(let i = 0; i < listing.length; i++) {
    if (listing[i].pid === data.pid) {
      dataFound = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  return dataFound;
};
```

Then you can use the returned `boolean` in your render to determine `success` or `failure` like this:

`<div if="checkOccurence(data, listing)"> Success </div> <div v-else>Failure</div>`

Comment: how to check in html side?

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to create a function which will determine if the id is already existing.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    data: {},
    listing: []
  },
  computed: {
   validatePID: function() {
     var ret = false;
       for(var idx in this.listing) {
          if (this.listing[idx].pid == this.data.pid) {
              ret = true;
              break;
          }
       }

       return ret;
    }
   },
  mounted: function() {
   this.data = {"pid": 109, "name": "Labs", "website": "service.com",  "status": true};
    this.listing.push({"pid": 109, "nams": "Labs","created_at": "2018-02-14", "validity": "2019-06-29", "views": 2, "gstno": "09485481072", "is_featured": false });
    this.listing.push({"pid": 112, "nams": "Labs12","created_at": "2018-02-15", "validity": "2019-06-29", "views": 2, "gstno": "09499481072", "is_featured": false });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <span v-if="validatePID">test</span>
 <span v-else>test2</span>
</div>
```

Here is your running code snippet.

Comment: how to check in the html part?

Comment: if you can access the data and listing inside validatePID function it should be like v-if="validatePID", and note the value changes during mounted lifecycle so basically I would make the function computed instead.

Answer (score 1):

define exists method in your methods ,

```
  methods: {
        exists: function() {
        var exist = false;
             var listings = self.listings;
             var data = self.data;
             for(var listing of listings) {
              if (listing.pid == data.pid) {
                  exist = true;
                  break;
              }
           }
           return exist;
        }
    }
```

And you should call the method like this,

```
   <div if="exists()"> Success </div> <div v-else> Failure</div>
```

Comment: listings is an array, so you should edit it to use `index-looping` instead of `object-looping`. :)

Comment: I think that is a json object? dont u think?

Comment: Which does not mean that it cannot contain an array

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution using arrow functions could be

```
const matchingListItem = listings.find(listItem => listItem.pid === data.pid);
```

Or if you don't need the matching listings item and just want to know if data.pid is contained in your listings array you could use this funtion

```
isDataInListings = (data, listings) => listings.some(item => item.pid === data.pid);
```